# reCaptcha file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed

Tags: php, ssl, file-get-contents, recaptcha

I'm using Google reCaptcha for my webpage.

In testing mode everything works fine. No SSL.

When I test my webpage in production environment the following errors occures:

> **Warning**:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code
>   1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in
>   **/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php**
>   on line **68**
>  
>  **Warning**:  file_get_contents():
>   Failed to enable crypto in
>   **/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php**
>   on line **68**
>  
>  **Warning**: 
>   file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify):
>   failed to open stream: operation failed in
>   **/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php**
>   on line **68**
>  ["invalid-json"]

I'm calling the reCaptcha API like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
                async defer></script>
```

as described on the developer page from google.

I'm hosting my webpage at hoststar.ch. There is TSL 1.2 running.

I hope somebody could help me.

Comment: did you call the google javascript files over https? Does the live host allow urls to be fetched using `file_get_contents`?

Comment: @RamRaider the second question I don't know, have to ask hoststar

Comment: try using `file_get_contents( 'http://example.com/' )` and see what happens on a test page - on live site. If you get a response then the hosts allow fopen wrappers, otherwise you might need to rethink...

Comment: @RamRaider if I do a http request it works, if I do an https request it doesn't work ... I cannot change the reCaptcha API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to your last comment I realise you cannot change Google's `reCaptcha api` - what I meant was simply to do a `file_get_contents` actually on `example.com` ( it does exist ) as a test to see if you can retrieve any content using that method as some webhosts disable the associated functionality.

However, with respect to the Google reCatcha API you might need to specify additional parameters to the `file_get_contents` function call, notably setting the `context` options specifically for SSL.

```
$secret = 'Your google secret';
$captcha = trim( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] );
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$captcha}&remoteip={$ip}";

$options=array(
    'ssl'=>array(
        'cafile'            => '/path/to/cacert.pem',
        'verify_peer'       => true,
        'verify_peer_name'  => true,
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create( $options );
$res=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url, FILE_TEXT, $context ) );
if( $res->success ){/* all good */}
else{ /* captcha failed */ }
```

If you don't already have a copy of [`cacert.pem`](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) or [`ca-bundle.crt`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt) you can download them from their respective links. The path to the `cafile` can use either - save a copy to your host and correct the path to suit your environment.

Comment: change the arrayname from http to ssl and adding the cert locally made it work, thank you .. look over at my next question about pass the params with a POST request ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856354/google-recaptcha-missing-input-response-missing-input-secret

Answer (score 4):

Change **file_get_contents** to **curl**. Here is the code,

Change-

```
$verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
 $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);  /*store json response*/
```

To this code :

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$verify = curl_exec($ch);

$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);  /*store json response*/
```

Please note **$secret** is the secret key stored on server side and **$response** is the recaptcha response send through post from front end.