# google reCaptcha - ["missing-input-response","missing-input-secret"]

Tags: php, ssl, recaptcha

I made some changes to ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post.php from Google API

```
class Post implements RequestMethod
{
    /**
    * URL to which requests are POSTed.
    * @const string
    */
    const SITE_VERIFY_URL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';

    /**
    * Submit the POST request with the specified parameters.
    *
    * @param RequestParameters $params Request parameters
    * @return string Body of the reCAPTCHA response
    */
    public function submit(RequestParameters $params)
    {
        /**
        * PHP 5.6.0 changed the way you specify the peer name for SSL context options.
        * Using "CN_name" will still work, but it will raise deprecated errors.
        */

        $cafile = dirname(__DIR__) . '/RequestMethod/ca-bundle.crt';
        $peer_key = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0', '<') ? 'CN_name' : 'peer_name';
        $options = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $params->toQueryString(),
                // Force the peer to validate (not needed in 5.6.0+, but still works
                'cafile' => $cafile,
                'verify_peer' => true,
                'verify_peer_name' => true,
                // Force the peer validation to use www.google.com
                $peer_key => 'www.google.com',
            ),
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        return file_get_contents(self::SITE_VERIFY_URL, false, $context);
    }
}
```

I added the following lines to the array and renamed it from http to ssl

```
'cafile' => $cafile 
'verify_peer_name' => true
```

Now the error form my following question disappeared. [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849880/recaptcha-file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed)

The new error is  ["missing-input-response","missing-input-secret"]

When I debug the $params from the submit method there the response and secret key are existing.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: The url `SITE_VERIFY_URL` is missing all the required querystring parameters ( namely `secret`,`response` and optionally `remoteip` ) - not sure you can simply pass them along in the `$context` as you appear to be doing

Comment: I tried to pass it in the url and its working now :) but I hope its not a security impact ... cause of the get method

Comment: that is never exposed to the end user - it runs at the server

Comment: thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: @RamRaider I'm using **Node.js and axios**.  To make it work, I had to place the paramaters ***in the url*** rather than in a params object as well.  Thanks!